# org.cyclonedx.exception.ParseException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character 't'

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I'm getting the next error, trying to read a this content from a xml file:

```
  org.cyclonedx.exception.ParseException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character 't' (code 116) in prolog; expected '<'
     at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,7]
```

This is the xm file content, I'm trying to read:

```
<content>terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = &quot;hashicorp/aws&quot;
      version = &quot;~&gt; 3.27&quot;
    }
  }
  required_version = &quot;&gt;= 0.14.7&quot;
}

data &quot;aws_caller_identity&quot; &quot;current&quot; {}

resource &quot;aws_s3_bucket&quot; &quot;inventory&quot; {
  bucket = &quot;regula-example-${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}&quot;
}
```

The code I'm using is pretty simple:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper()
return (Bom)this.mapper.readValue(reader, Bom.class);
```

And I'm always getting the next error, I tried to modify the Content, but not pretty sure, what could be the error, any ideas?

Comment: Is the closing tag for <content> missing? Please also post your Bom.class

Comment: Suggest checking the input from the `reader`.  E.g. `xmlMapper.readValue("terraform...", Bom.class)` results in `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character 't' (code 116) in prolog; expected '<'`